# Running Apache2 Server along with Node Server [NGINX]

Tags: node.js, apache, nginx

I have a server with several node.Js app installed. I follow this guide to set up my reverse proxy setting: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab

So my `/etc/nginx/conf.d` folder is crowded with Nginx configuration files, like:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name my-domain.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;  // my node app runs on port 3001
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Then, I installed and managed to run my `apache2` server on port 3002. I tried to use this configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name my-wordpress-blog.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/wordpress-folder-name; // yes, this is for wordpress 
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

The problem is: whenever I try to access `my-wordpress-blog.com`, it reroutes me to `my-wordpress-blog.com/html` with 404 error: `The requested URL /htmlhtml/ was not found on this server..` So how to set this up correctly ? Thx

Comment: Not a solution but a question. Why dont you use nginx to serve the wordpress directly instead of using apache?

Comment: @PerroVerd What ?! I don't know about that.  I always use apache to serve my wordpress blog. I'll do some research about this. Thank you, your answer surprises me!

Comment: nginx and apache are both webservers. Instead installing apache and mod_php5 you install php5-fpm and let nginx use it. You will reduce the resources used and response times because of the reduction of the layer complexity. You have a lot of documentation both in wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx and nginx http://wiki.nginx.org/Wordpress

Comment: So it turns out that I don't need apache at all. Do you have sample configuration script to set this up ? If so, please write it down as an answer. I want my wordpress accessible both with my-wordpress-blog.com and subdomain www.my-wordpress-blog.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested my configuration script for my own wordpress installation. Its based in the default nginx and php5-fpm packages provided by Debian. Not sure if its the best configuration, because its old, but it works ;)

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site.conf

```
# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for php
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
        ## Your website name goes here.
        server_name example.com;
        ## Your only path reference.
        root /var/www/your-wp-installation;
        ## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Also I include the fastcgi.conf file but I think its the default one

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```